# Msg 8120: Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I have EMP table in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [MGR_ID] INT, 
    [DEPT_ID] INT, 
    [NAME] VARCHAR(30), 
    [SAL] INT, 
    [DOJ] DATE
)
```

When I am executing this query

```
Select NAME, MAX(SAL) as Salary FROM EMP;
```

I'm bumping into this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Column 'EMP.NAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please help

P.S.

Potentially the reason for the above-mentioned error is that I have multiple rows in the `NAME` column and `MAX` aggregate function returns only one row.

Comment on Gordon's answer:

> I actually want to return a name of an Employee(s) with the second highest salary

Comment: if its correct solution then instead of editing my answer mark it as answer.

Comment: Apart from Aggregate functions all remain Columns should be in group by. It will resolve issue in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Name, Max(sal) as salary from employee group by Name
```

So when you use any aggregate function in sql like count, max, min etc we have to specify those columns from select list which we want to be thw grouping column of result set

Comment: Please add an explanation with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the name associated with the maximum salary, then use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
select top 1 name, sal
from employee
order by sal desc;
```

If you want all values, even when there are ties, then use `TOP WITH TIES`.

Comment: I actually want to return a name of an Employee(s) with the second highest salary.

Comment: Then use `offset 1 fetch first 1 row only` instead of `top 1`.

Comment: The problem here that my table have many Employees with the MAX(SAL), so I really do not know how many rows to offset

Comment: As an idea - DENSE_RANK functions could be used:

Comment: WITH [output] AS 
(
SELECT NAME, SAL, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SAL DESC) AS [RANK], 
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SAL DESC) AS [DENSE_RANK] 
FROM EMP
)
SELECT TOP 2 SAL, NAME FROM [output] WHERE DENSE_RANK = 2;

Comment: The only thing that is hard-coded here is the value "2" in the SELECT TOP; if anyone have a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: You can parameterize the value instead of hard coding it if you want; makes no difference to the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that you wanted to return the name of Employee(s) with the second highest salary. You need to use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) to achieve this:

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SAL DESC)
    FROM UsrLic
)
SELECT
    NAME, SAL
FROM Cte
WHERE RN = 2
```

Comment: Also possible solution is to use OFFSET: Select NAME, SAL FROM EMP Order BY SAL DESC offset 2 rows fetch first 2 row only; But in this case OFFSET and FETCH values are hard-coded based on the data in the table .

Answer (score -1):

I had this same error and what caused it was an error in my variable names while writing my group by statement

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).